# How can I refactor the event listeners for my select elements and buttons?

Tags: javascript, arrays, event-handling, event-listener

I'll like some help please with using the DRY principle to refactor this code. What would a function for this look like?

```
let fruitPrice =[+QOne.value,+QTwo.value,+QThree.value,+QFour.value,+QFive.value];



QOne.addEventListener('change', e=>{
    fruitPrice=+e.target.value;

});

QTwo.addEventListener('change', e=>{
    fruitPrice=+e.target.value;
    console.log(fruitPrice);

});
```

this is the event listeners for the buttons

```
buyApple.addEventListener('click',e=>{
    // console.log(fruitPrice/2);
    const applesBought=fruitPrice/2;
    displayMsg.innerHTML=`<h2>You've bought ${applesBought} item</h2>`

    if (fruitPrice/2>1){
        displayMsg.innerHTML=`<h2>You've bought ${applesBought} items</h2>`
    }

    const price=document.getElementById('price');
    price.innerHTML=`<h2>Price:$${fruitPrice}</h2>`;


});

buyOrange.addEventListener('click',e=>{
    // console.log(fruitPrice/2);
    const orangesBought=fruitPrice/2;
    displayMsg.innerHTML=`<h2>You've bought ${orangesBought} item</h2>`

    if (fruitPrice/2>1){
        displayMsg.innerHTML=`<h2>You've bought ${orangesBought} items</h2>`
    }

    const price=document.getElementById('price');
    price.innerHTML=`<h2>Price:$${fruitPrice}</h2>`;


});
```

The function I tried to create isn't running. I typed something like:

```
fruitPrice.forEach(function(entry){
    entry.addEventListener('change',e=>{
        console.log(e.target.value);
    })


})
```

Comment: `fruitPrice` is an array of strings, you need an array of the elements, like `fruitPriceEls = [QOne, QTwo ...];`.

Comment: Doesn't the plus sign do the job of changing them from a string into a number?

Comment: Indeed, but you can't attach events to numbers either ...